# Users can't reset their passwords anymore on Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I did incorrectly activate (and then deactivate) a third-party SSO on a Google Apps account (aka linked to a domain name). Now that the third-party SSO is deactivated, users can log again into their Google Apps accounts; however, when a user tries to change her password, she keeps being redirected to the "old" third-party SSO URL. This is very odd because the third-party SSO is now deactivated in the Google Admin console.

How can I restore the initial behavior concerning password reset for Google Apps accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to remove the URL's from the SSO Setup section in the Security Page.  This is where your Google Apps account is looking for the Change Password URL.

[image]

If you have removed it, try to re-enable SSO, press save.  Then make sure all the URL's are empty, press save.  Lastly untick the SSO option and press save again.  Hopefully that will tell your Google Apps that the URL is gone.